# Push code to GitHub

Tags: github

I'm new to GitHub and I want to push an existing project to my GitHub account. I've installed GitHub for Mac, and created a repository, and added all the files of this project.

Then I clicked on Publish and could see the repository on the website.

But there is no any source code file at all, only 3 files (LICENSE, README and .gitignore) which were initially created when creating the repository.

BTW, I've tried "git remote add origin https://github.com/SiyiStephanieYao/Task-Time-Manager-v0.0.1.git" in command, and it said "fatal: remote origin already exists."
I also tried "git push -u origin --all", and it said "Everything up-to-date".
But the code files are still not on the website.

Anyone could help me?
Thank you.

Comment: did you run `git add --all` before the commit?

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to commit.

Try

```
git add --all
git commit -m 'commit message'
```

Then you push.

Comment: It has been addressed. Thank you.